# Unable to read CSV in pyspark with special characters [ ] included

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have been trying to read from a CSV with pyspark where the filename contains special characters. However, spark throws me an error . Is there any way to read this file using spark ?.

I have tried reading the file with name "[dbo].[sample_To_text_Common].csv". I also tried with escaping character as well.The same file has read in Azure Data Bricks Notebook using spark by playing with filename.

Code that worked in azure data bricks

```
data_file = "[dbo].[sample_To_text_Common].csv".replace("[","?").replace("]","?")

df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv(data_file)
```

In spark local mode it throws me an error like below ( i tried the above in local mode as well )

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("[dbo].[sample_To_text_Common].csv")


pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Path does not exist: '[dbo].[sample_To_text_Common].csv';"
```

Comment: in the first code block you apply 2 replaces, in the second you don't

Comment: I have tried the replace version of the filename in the second block as well. it's the same error.